# How to delete cmd-like page in my software?

Tags: cmd, window

I have a GTK+ program. When I run it two windows open: a blank command prompt

[image]

and the main GUI.

How can I get rid of the command prompt window?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the libraries you use, and everything to do with how you compiled sepand.exe as a console program instead of a gui program. Fix that, and this console window will go away.

Comment: @ Michael Urman: I compiled a c++ code (include gtk+ and opencv libraries) with Visual Studio 2013 and I design a setup with InstallShield2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem: I add `#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")` on top of my code and I get rid of the command prompt window.